# I'd like to get a list of all the groups that I can add and remove members from

Tags: powershell

Recently started a new job and was added to over 300 AD Security Groups as a secondary owner.  As a secondary owner, I can add and remove group members.  I would like to run a PowerShell script to list all the groups I can add and remove members from.   I tried the below:

[(Powershell) Method to return a list of groups where a specific user has 'write member' security](https://serverfault.com/questions/456964/powershell-method-to-return-a-list-of-groups-where-a-specific-user-has-write)

Neither code snippet returned any results for me.

Comment: Do you mean the msExchCoManagedBy attribute?

Comment: I think so?  I'm new to powershell so Im not 100% sure....sorry

Comment: This isn't a PowerShell thing. We need to know what you mean by "Secondary Owner".

Comment: Simply put, I can add and remove members from the AD groups, however I am not the user that is listed as the "ManagedBy" in the group properties.  I'd like to get a list of all the groups that I can add and remove members from

Comment: `I'd like to get a list of all the groups that I can add and remove members from`. That's what the title should be.

Comment: @GregAskew I adjusted the title and question as suggested.  Thank you